# Extract url from text file next to certain string

Tags: html, powershell, url, text-parsing

I have a large text file that contains something like:

```
View this email in your browser (https://us15.campaign-archive.com/?e=3D1460&u=3Df6e2bb1612577510b&id=3D2c8be)
```

Sometimes, part of the URL goes onto the next line.

I simply need to extract that URL using PowerShell, without the brackets (parentheses), so that I can download it as a HTML file.

I've tried doing this in batch which I'm most familiar with, but it's proving impossible and seems this would be possible in PowerShell.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following uses [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based operators and .NET APIs.

In both solutions, `-replace '\r?\n'` is used to remove any embedded newlines (line breaks) from the URL(s) found, using the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator (`\r?\n` is a regex that matches both Windows-format CRLF and Unix-format LF-only newlines).

- If you only need *one* or the *first* URL, use the [`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch), which - if it returns `$true` - reports what was matched in the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches) variable.

```bash
# Sample multi-line input string.
# To read such a string from a file, use, e.g.:
#     $str = Get-Content -Raw file.txt
$str = @'
  Initial text.

  View this email in your browser (https://us15.campaign-archive.com/?e=3D1460&u=3Df6e2b
b1612577510b&id=3D2c8be)

  More text.
'@

# Find the (first) embedded URL...
if ($str -match '(?<=\()https?://[^)]+') {
  # ... remove any line breaks from it, and output the result.
  $Matches.0 -replace '\r?\n'
}
```

- If you need *all* (or a fixed count) of matches, direct use of the [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches) .NET API is required:

```bash
# Extract *all* URLs and remove any embedded line breaks from each
[regex]::Matches(
  $str, 
  '(?<=\()https?://[^)]+'
).Value -replace '\r?\n'
```

For an explanation of the first regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/pxCvQI/1).

Comment: Is it possible to narrow this down by the "View this email in your browser" text as sometimes the url can be between other characters or just be a space or rarely not the first url?

Comment: @Coder, you can include the preceding text in the look-behind assertion: `(?<=\bView\s+this\s+email\s+in\s+your\s+browser\s+\()https?://[^)]+')` This uses `\s+` for flexible whitespace matching, but if you know that only a single space each separates the words and there can be no line breaks, you can use spaces

Comment: i've tried that but when i run the script nothing is returned, is it because of the brackets which sometimes can be < > around the url?

Comment: @Coder, try replacing `\(` with `[(<]` and `[^)]` with `[^)>]`

Comment: so this? 
if ($str -match '(?<=\bView\s+this\s+email\s+in\s+your\s+browser[(<])https?://[^)>]+') {
doesn't return anything

Comment: @Coder, you're missing a `\s+` after `browser`. Try `(?<=\bView\s+this\s+email\s+in\s+your\s+browser\s+[(<])https?://[^)>]+`

Comment: So i have this now `if ($str -match '(?<=\bView\s+this\s+email\s+in\s+your\s+browser\s+[(<])https?://[^)>]+') {` but doesnt return the url

Comment: @Coder, to be clear: `-match` returns `$true` or `$false`, and, if it returns `$true`, you need to get the matched text from the `$Matches` variable, as shown in the answer. If you're still having trouble, I suggest asking a _new_ question that includes a [mcve].